# 置換のときに登録される「検索する文字列」の履歴について

Tags: emeditor

メニューバーから検索(S)＞置換(R)、と操作すると、テキストの1行目にある最初の単語や記号などが「検索する文字列」に自動で登録されてしまい煩わしいです。
テキストの1行目が改行のみの場合は、この現象は発生しないようですが、バグなのか仕様なのか分かりません。
仕様だとすれば、置換でテキストの最初の単語や記号を「検索する文字列」に登録させない方法はあるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

[検索する文字列] ボックスの右の [>] ボタンをクリックして表示されるメニューから、[最後に使った値]、または [固定値] を選択すれば、ご希望のような動作になります。

[image: EmEditor 置換]

Comment: 画像付きで分かりやすく回答して頂きありがとうございました。
無事、解決致しました。